# Authentication to a RESTful web service in an AngularJS 2

Tags: angular, rest, api, restful-authentication

i want to consume an api that return a json file, but i need to do the authentification in my header HTTP i don't know how to really do it,

my typeScript service code is :

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import{Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class PostService{
    constructor(private _http: Http){
    }

    getPosts(){
       return  this._http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

and my app code :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {PostService} from './post.service';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import {Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>get webservice</h1>


    `,
    providers:[PostService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class AppComponent { 


    constructor(private _postService: PostService){    this._postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => console.log(posts));
    }
}

and my api link is like : 

header HTTP :
key : Authorization
the contents : Basic VXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

can anyone explain to me please? thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do something like this.

```
import {Http,Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class PostService{

    //add auth data to headers
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Some Auth Key', 'Some Auth Value');

    //then you can make your http request like you normally would    

}
```

Comment: it did not resolve my problem, i'm having these errors : 
[errors][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/H0WHe.png

Comment: Error1 is because your server can't find favicon.ico (not related to your question).  Error2 is because you don't seem to have cors enabled on your server and are making the request from localhost (not related to your question). Without fixing Error2 you won't be able to test sending headers, so I would suggest starting there.  Then once that is fixed see if this question has been answered well enough for you.